# MongoDB db.createUser() schema version error

Tags: mongodb

I get this error when trying to create an admin user on a fresh **MongoDB 2.6.8** install. My machine is running Ubuntu 14.04.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.8
connecting to: test
> use admin
switched to db admin

> db.createUser(
  {
    user: "user",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

> Error: couldn't add user: User and role management commands require
>   auth data to have schema version 3 but found 5 at
>   src/mongo/shell/db.js:1054

I had MongoDB 3.0.1 installed before, I removed it because it was not compatible with some other software I use. I executed `sudo apt-get purge` on MongoDB to remove all config files before installing 2.6.8.

I have tried this, but it seems like I need a downgrade function:

```
> db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 3 })
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Do not know how to upgrade auth schema from version 5",
    "code" : 69
}
```

Can you help me? Why is this happening?

Comment: What happens if you try running the [**`authSchemaUpgrade`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-upgrade-authorization/#upgrade-authorization-schema) command `db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 1 })`?

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: The docs mention that _In case of error, you may safely rerun the authSchemaUpgrade command._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work by purging MongoDB:

`sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org mongodb-org-*`

And then deleting the content inside this folder, this holds all the databases:

```
sudo rm -fr /var/lib/mongodb/
```

After that I installed **2.6.8** again and I was able to add a new user. So it seems like purge does not remove all files needed to downgrade.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.8
connecting to: test
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.createUser(
   {
     user: "user",
     pwd: "password",
     roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
   }
 )
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "user",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```